# Timer doesn't contain in System.Threading at Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, timer, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I used `System.Threading.Timer` in `Xamarin.Android`.

How I can use the same class in `Xamarin.Forms`?
(I want to transfer my project from Xamarin.Android in Xamarin.Forms)

```
public static System.Threading.Timer timer;
if (timer == null)
{
    System.Threading.TimerCallback tcb = MyMethod;
    timer = new System.Threading.Timer(tcb, null, 700, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
}
else
{
    timer.Change(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
    timer.Change(700, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

Comment: Did you try [`System.Timers`](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Timers.Timer/)?

Comment: No. I have the project on Xamarin.Android.
This project use System.Threading.Timer.

I need to transfer this project from Xamarin.Android to Xamarin.Forms

Comment: Am I get you right, that you are only looking for a delayed execution of a method without having a periodic method call?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`System.Threading.Timer` is not available in PCL code.
You can use the `Xamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer` method instead as explained here:
http://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Device.StartTimer/

Comment: I also use TimerCallback and Change method

Comment: You pass a timer callback as the second parameter. It's a method that returns a `bool`. Return `true` when you want to execute that callback again or return `false` when you want to stop it.

Comment: You can find documentation here actually: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/platform-specifics/#Device.StartTimer

Comment: Now `System.Threading.Timer` available in Xamarin.Forms if you are targeting netstandard2

Answer (score 5):

For PCL you can create your own using async/await features. Another advantage of this approach - your timer method implementation can await on async methods inside timer handler

```
public sealed class AsyncTimer : CancellationTokenSource
{
    public AsyncTimer (Func<Task> callback, int millisecondsDueTime, int millisecondsPeriod)
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(millisecondsDueTime, Token);
            while (!IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await callback();
                if (!IsCancellationRequested)
                    await Task.Delay(millisecondsPeriod, Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        });
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
            Cancel();

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
{
  ...
  var timer = new AsyncTimer(OnTimer, 0, 1000);
}

private async Task OnTimer()
{
   // Do something
   await MyMethodAsync();
}
```

Comment: How I can use TimerCallback and Change method?

Comment: This is a great solution.   one question: how do I stop the timer once I no longer need it?

Comment: It inherits from CancellationToken, so you can execute .Cancel() method on timer object. It works, because internally it checks IsCancellationRequested and also passes this Token to Task.Delay() calls. However your own callback function will not receive this token. You can change code to add this feature though.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found solution for the timer in Xamarin.forms

1. `Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000), OnTimerTick);`
   // TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000) specify the time in milisecond
   //OnTimerTick it is function that will be executed return boolean

   2. private bool OnTimerTick()
              {  // code to be executed 
                  lblTime.Text = newHighScore .ToString();
                  newHighScore++;
                  return true;
              }

I hope you get my point easily
thanks.