# How to use properly Timer with thread in Xamarin?

Tags: multithreading, timer, cross-platform, xamarin.forms, stopwatch

I would like to use a timer , to execute a time, pause and stop.

has spent several days that i search how to use in the best way a timer because, as you know, it does not exist a timer directly unless to create it.

so, I followed these informations by creating a timer, using a timespan, timercallback and stopwatch :

[Timer doesn't contain in System.Threading at Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32050052/timer-doesnt-contain-in-system-threading-at-xamarin-forms)

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/System.Timers/

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch/

I think that stopwatch is the best. And with several  manupulations, i have what i wanted, but the problem is that the time runs out that every time I press the run button, when I should press once on the button.

With a Thread too, I had done but it dis not change anything. I do not know why it do that.

And it is the same with a Datetime, I would like that the time of the Datetime continues to run while i did not press another button to stop it.

If someone would have an idea avout it, really thank you in advance.

Comment: You haven't actually asked us a question.  SO is a Q&A site, so to get a good Answer it helps to ask a good Question first.  I would suggest you post the relevant portions of your code and try to more concisely explain the problem you're having with it.  As it is it's very difficult to understand what you want.

Comment: Hi, yes, I can be more precise. In fact, I need to run my chronometer (a button with a label for display) but the problem is that currently, I need to press everytime the button to run the chronometer miliseconds by milliseconds, instead of press just one time on the button.

Answer (score 0):

As I said, i think i have what i would. But I need to press just one time the button to run the chronometer instead of press it everytime with an incrementation of time milliseconds by milliseconds.

So, here is my chronoTimer.cs for that :

```
class TimerExpand
        {
            public int counter = 0;
            public System.Threading.Timer threadTimer;
        }


 public static void Temps()
        {

            TimerExpand t_expand = new TimerExpand();

            TimerCallback timerDelegate = new TimerCallback(GetTime);

            System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(timerDelegate, t_expand, 0, 1000);

            t_expand.threadTimer = timer;


  }

 public static void GetTime(object etat)
         {
           TimerExpand t_expand = (TimerExpand) etat;
            t_expand.counter++;

        }


 private DateTime actualDate;
 public static Stopwatch sw;
```

And then on my buttonTimer_OnClicked method :

```
 actualDate = DateTime.Now;
 sw = new Stopwatch();



                sw.Start();

    labelChrono.Text = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}:{3:00}", sw.Elapsed.Hours, sw.Elapsed.Minutes, sw.Elapsed.Seconds,
                   sw.Elapsed.Milliseconds);

 labelDate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();

            Temps();

}
```